# 2021-02-16 10:43:57,123 ERROR in app: Exception on / GET?

Tags: flask, tkinter, embed

I want to embed/put a tkinter gui in a flask app, but the code i made seems not to be rendering/show and gives this error when i run my code:

```
[2021-02-16 10:43:57,123] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\User\untitled0.py", line 14, in my_app
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2369, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1326, in _options
    v = self._register(v)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1372, in _register
    self.tk.createcommand(name, f)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Feb/2021 10:43:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

also when i want to run the flask web server it shows `Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.`

```
from flask import Flask
from webbrowser import open

app = Flask(__name__)
root = Tk()
root.title("Tkinter")

@app.route('/')
def my_app():
    def click():
        l = Label(root, text = "You Clicked!").pack()
        

    b = Button(root, text = "Click Me!", command = click).pack()
        
    return(root)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    open('http://127.0.0.1:5000/')
    app.run()
    #root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you trying to run tkinter on a server? It's not designed to work that way. It's possible if you just want to use flask locally, though.

Comment: No i am just trying to display my tkinter app in a web server

Comment: You can't do that. At least, not without a _lot_ of work. Tkinter needs a display, and a browser isn't a display from the perspective of tkinter.

Comment: oh is there any alternative gui making modules that can do what i want to do?